# Can we manage products filtration by category wise in Magento 2 admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, products

How can I manage the order of products by using category wise instead of SKU name etc..?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, but without more information it's hard to determine exactly what you're asking.

Try creating a product attribute with the **Default Label** as **Categories**. In the **Storefront Properties** section set **Use in Layered Navigation as Yes**.

Then navigate to **Catalog > Categories** and select or create a category. In the Categories **Display Settings**, set **Anchor as Yes**.

That category should now be visible and filterable. A basic guide can be found [here](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-layered-navigation-with-filterable-attributes-magento-2.html).

Comment: Sorry, I'm asking about all products list. Can we search by categories wise? I have the number of categories available in my store. I want to search all related "Living" products at the same time. Product list has the filter but it doesn't show category wise. Do we need to code any for this?